# Get current index of an item with Object.entries().map

Tags: javascript

I know it is probably a silly question but I can' find an answer by myself, so..

How can I get current `index` with this construction `.map(([key, value])`?

to access it inside the map function bellow

```
     return (
        <Fragment>
            {Object.entries(props.values).map(([key, value]) => {
                return (
                    <Button
                        key={key}
                        value={value}                      
                    />
                );
            })}
        </Fragment>
     );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can obtain an index from callback in map

```
 return (
    <Fragment>
        {Object.entries(props.values).map(([key, value], index) => {
            return (
                <Button
                    key={key}
                    value={value}                      
                />
            );
        })}
    </Fragment>
 );
```

Please check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Thanks Man, I tried all the possible combinations, but from the left side))

Comment: You welcome. Please mark the solution to indicate that the question is properly answered. Thanks!